# ajax post to controller and display into custom element file

Tags: ajax, cakephp, post, controller

i need to fetch data from database from controller file and display into element file and ajax value showing in inspect element and also when i alert in ajax it is showing that value is going to controller.

but problem is that how can i echo or print ajax value in controller to fetch data from database and display it into element file?

how can i render custom element file in controller function?

**ajax script**

```
<script>
 $('#categories .accordion .tablist .tablistitem').on('click', function () {
 event.preventDefault();
 $(".accordion li").removeClass("active");
 var  $li = $(this);
 $liid = $li.attr('id');
 $slug = $li.data('slug');
 $li.addClass("active");

 $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
 $('#categories_info').show();

  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/reviews/getsubcategories',
  data: {"selectid":$liid },
  dataType:"text",

  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {    
        alert(data);        
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert(textStatus);


  }
  });
  });



</script>
```

**controller function**

```
function getsubcategories()
{
    echo $selectid= $_POST['selectid'];

    return $selectid;

}
```

**element file**

```
$SubCategoryObj = cri('Reviews');
$selectid = $SubCategoryObj->getMainCategories();
echo $selectid;
```

Comment: which version of cake?

Comment: @JasonJoslin cakephp version is 2.0.13

Answer (score 1):

What you have done so far is mostly right, however in the past I have just created the view as normal in the `View/Reviews` folder.

In the controller set your data:

**/app/Controller/ReviewsController.php**

```
public function getsubcategories()
{
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $data = /**code to get data**/

    $this->set('data', $data);

}
```

**/app/View/Reviews/getsubcategories.ctp**

```
<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
```

another option is to create the same view above but put it in file `app/View/Ajax/json.ctp`

And then inside the controller the last thing you call in the getsubcategories action is.

`$this->render('Ajax/json');`

In my experience elements are used inside views and not as replacements of views

Comment: which part is not working? I've definitely managed to get this method working for me in the past.

Comment: function getsubcategories()
{
    $data = "this is testing page";

    $this->set('data', $data);

}

i have created getsubcategories.ctp and <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>

Comment: In your ajax method you have set dataType as text yet your data property is actually json. change your datatype to json. in your getsubcategories() action write `debug($this->request->data);exit;`. Do you get the ID you are posting in your alert? Also I like to use `console.log()` instead of `alert ()` to debug my javascript. Can then see the output regardless of datatype in the browsers console tab of the inspector tools

Comment: and also how do i render ReviewsController.ctp in element file or controller?

Comment: If you can get that far i'm unsure how you cannot get to the view. Double check your folder structure and view name fit all the cake conventions and you shouldnt have a problem. Oh and 1 other thing. Should set `$this->layout = 'ajax'`. have updated my answer to match

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109994/discussion-between-farhan-dharsi-and-jason-joslin).